# Java JNI: Specify path to dependent shared library

Tags: java, java-native-interface

I built a JNI library `libmyjni.dylib` and it is linked with `libthirdparty.dylib`. While starting my Java application, I set `-Djava.library.path=/path/to/native/libs` but that path is not being used to load `libthirdparty.dylib`. Java is always looking for `libthirdparty.dylib` under `<project_root>/lib` folder. What parameter do I set so as to look for `libthirdparty.dylib` in the same path as `java.library.path`?

This is the error I get if I don't put `libthirdparty.dylib` under `<project_root>/lib`. I also tried creating `/etc/ld.so.conf` with path to `libthirdparty.dylib` in int but that did not help as well.

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: <java_library_path>/libmyjni.dylib: dlopen(<java_library_path>/libmyjni.dylib, 1): Library not loaded: lib/libthirdparty.dylib
  Referenced from: <java_library_path>/libmyjni.dylib
  Reason: image not found
```

Comment: `java.library.path` is for JNI libraries only, not libraries they depend on. The system path is used for those, which is system-dependent, and you haven't told us the system.

Comment: @EJP Have to support both OS X and Linux.

Comment: @EJP is right, you should set PATH, LD_LIBRARY_PATH, or DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH (on Windows, Linux, or OSX respectively).

Comment: @CHmoonKa Please make your comment as an answer so that it can be accepted.

Answer (score 0):

`java.library.path` is for JNI libraries only, not libraries they depend on. The system path is used for those, which is system-dependent: set `PATH`, `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, or `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` (on Windows, Linux, or OSX respectively)

Based on @user207421 and @CHmoonKa comments to the question.